# Can't get my Nintendo 64 working

Tags: nintendo-64

I have a Vizio Tesla 39 TV and have tried literally every combination on the internet to get my Nintendo 64 to work.
It will not work no matter the combination.
My TV has been sitting in the basement for 2 years, so is that a possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, the game I was using to test it out (Mario kart 64) was not working, but when I tested it with a different game (golden eye 007) it worked.